# Truncate only certain decimal values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe:

| client_id | title | position_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Baker | 15.1 |
| 123 | Chef | 16.0 |
| 123 | Farmer | 17.2 |

I need to truncate the decimal only when it is .0 so my outcome will look like this:

| client_id | title | position_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Baker | 15.1 |
| 123 | Chef | 16 |
| 123 | Farmer | 17.2 |

I am relatively new to using Pandas in Python. Does anyone have a recommendation? I recently figured out how to use

```
df['Hourly Rate'] = df['Hourly Rate'].apply(lambda x: format(float(x),".2f"))
```

to always add two decimals to my column. Would something similar to this be used?

Comment: this is for display only right?  You still want to keep the actual value as is?

Comment: To set the display precision you can do : `pandas.set_option('display.precision', 2)` if that helps

Comment: No, I apologize, I meant that I want to change the value totally in my CSV file. Not just display.

Comment: You are going to have to convert this column to a string in order to achieve this output.

Comment: Do you want the result to still be usable as a number afterward, or is conversion to string acceptable?

Comment: A string will be okay.

Comment: This works to an extent: df['Position Code'] = df['Position Code'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip('.0'))

Comment: When the Position Code is 2600.0 and I use the code above it strips all the zeros out and leaves me with 26 instead of 2600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are OK with strings in the columns then you could use:

```
df['position_code']=df['position_code'].map(lambda x: format(float(x), ".0f") if (abs(float(x)-int(x)) < 1e-6) else format(float(x), ".1f"))
```

The 1e-6 is used to avoid any remnant float rounding issues

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this out:

```
df['position_code'] = df['position_code'].apply(lambda x: str(int(x)) if x % 1 == 0 else x)
```